# PHP AJAX not working with htaccess

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

I wrote a simple code for htaccess to prevent .php extensions. But from then my ajax code is not working. This is my .htaccess code

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

On removing the fourth line ajax is working, but both urls localhost/sample/hello.php and localhost/sample/hello are working! (as that is not intended)

My sample ajax script

```
$.post('BaseClass.php', {
  action: 'login'
},
```

I have BaseClass.php file in same directory
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your htaccess blocking request with .php extension try to use it without extension

like that

```
$.post('BaseClass', {
  action: 'login'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference as far as HTTP requests go between an AJAX call and a regular page request. The only difference is that one is done by the user (regular page requests), while the other is done by the browser using JavaScript in the background (AJAX).

So, you cannot use `.htaccess` rules to disable PHP scripts but enable them for AJAX calls, since they are really the same thing. If you want to make sure that a PHP script is only invoked as an AJAX call, check for specific request variables (e.g. `if (isset($_POST["ajax_action"])) { ... }`). But beware: this is **not a security mechanism**, since anybody can read the JavaScript source code and make the AJAX requests manually.